# Given a date how to get Sunday & Saturday of that week

Tags: datetime, calendar, titanium

I want to get the Sunday & Saturday of the week from which a date is provided.
I have access to the following functions only:

- `getDate()` returns a number from 0-6 (0 being sunday)
- `getDay()`  returns a number from 1-31
- `getMonth()`  returns a number from 0-11
- `getFullYear()`  returns the current year

I am doing this on titanium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your description above, I came up with:

```
var sat = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), 6 - input.getDate() + getDay());
var sun = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), getDay() + (input.getDate() - 6));
```

If I follow the MDN doc, I come up with (works in Ti too):

```
var sat = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), 6 - input.getDay() + input.getDate());
var sun = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), input.getDate() + (input.getDay() - 6));
```

Where input is a javascript Date object.

The date object will take care or changing the month and/or year if necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this code is for a sunday through saturday week. For a monday through sunday week:    var sun = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), 7 - input.getDay() + input.getDate());    though you've probably figured that one out by now. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: Out of curiosity (as I am not familiar with Titanium, just from standpoint of programming logic and clarity of the code), why do you switch around last functions in the expression (lacks consistency?) and what is the point of adding parenthesis around `input.getDay() - 6`?