# How to get Saturdays and Sundays (dates) of a month + JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a date is given (for example-"2014-01-07") ,I want to access that specific month (January 2014) and get the **date number** of the **Saturdays** and **Sundays** of that month.

In this case,
4,11,18,25 --Saturdays
5,12,19,26 -- Sundays

I want to use java script because this is a front end development.
Help me out with this..Thnkz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/z75ku/)**

```
var d = new Date();
var getTot = daysInMonth(d.getMonth(),d.getFullYear()); //Get total days in a month
var sat = new Array();   //Declaring array for inserting Saturdays
var sun = new Array();   //Declaring array for inserting Sundays

for(var i=1;i<=getTot;i++){    //looping through days in month
    var newDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),i)
    if(newDate.getDay()==0){   //if Sunday
        sun.push(i);
    }
    if(newDate.getDay()==6){   //if Saturday
        sat.push(i);
    }

}
console.log(sat);
console.log(sun);


function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

In **sat** and **sun** `Array()` you can get the Saturdays and Sundays of particular month

Comment: you could have used the first saturday or sunday finding in a month and then simply add 7 days to it to get the next sunday or saturday, thus reducing the size of loop and making it more efficient...

Comment: Just a note that, although the embedded code was edited by hari some time ago, the FIDDLE still has the Sunday and Saturday arrays backwards.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy using [getDate](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) method:

```
var my_date = "2014-01-07".split('-')
var year = parseInt(my_date[0]);
var month = parseInt(my_date[1])-1;

var saturdays = [];
var sundays = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); i++) 
{    
    var date = new Date(year, month, i);

    if (date.getDay() == 6)
    {
       saturdays.push(date);
    } 
    else if (date.getDay() == 0)
    {
        sundays.push(date);    
    }
};

console.log(sundays, saturdays);
```

Comment: IT WAS MORE USEFUL FOR ME THAN OTHER ANSWERS THANKS YOU A LOOT! SAVED A LOT OF TIME :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var pred = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();

var nowd;
var sat_array = "";
var sun_array = "";


for (i=1;i<=pred;i++) {

  try {
    console.log(d.getFullYear()+ "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + i);
    nowd = new Date(d.getFullYear()+ "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + i)

    if (nowd.getUTCDay() == 5)
    {
        sat_array = sat_array + "," + i;
    }

    if (nowd.getUTCDay() == 6)
    {
        sun_array = sun_array + "," + i;
    }


  }
  catch(e) {
      return;
  }

}

console.log("SAT list : " +sat_array);
console.log("SUN list : " +sun_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your discription above
you can use -

```
var sat = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), 6 - input.getDate() + getDay());
var sun = new Date(input.getFullYear(), input.getMonth(), getDay() + (input.getDate() - 6));
```

Put that code in for loop and add 7 till month changes.
and subtract 7 till month changes.

javascript input date will takecare of month and year for you.

Comment: `ReferenceError: getDay is not defined`...
Copy+paste of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10523173/674033
Except Kapil Dave didn't pick the working example...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getWend(date){
    var dArray = date.split('-')
    for(i=0;i<=31;i++){
        var nDay = dArray[0]+'-'+dArray[1]+'-'+i.toString()
        if([6,0].includes(new Date(nDay).getDay()))
        console.log(new Date(nDay).toString())
    }
}

getWend('2023-10-27')
```